# Провели широкую рекламу

Tags: перевод, грамматика

Здравствуйте,

I am struggling with the phrase included into the double parenthesis. How should "широкую рекламу" be translatated in this context?

"(Мы провели ((широкую рекламу))) по телевидению и в метро в Москве и в Санкт-Петербурге."

Большое спасибо,

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's most probably a misuse of *мы провели широкую рекламную кампанию* which means "we've conducted a broad advertising campaign".

Synecdoches like this (*реклама* "advertising" instead of *рекламная кампания* "advertising campaign") are quite common in professional jargons but should not normally be used outside them.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to rephrase it in English, eliminating the need to use a noun.

> It [the product] was widely advertised on TV and in subways in Moscow and St. Petersburg.

Answer (score 0):

"We launched a widespread advertising campaign on tv as well as in the Moscow and St. Petersburg Metros."

Comment: *провели* means it's already over. Is "we launched" the right phrase to convey this meaning?

Comment: Yes, it can refer to the beginning or the completed campaign in hindsight.